# Error in loading a model through Pickle in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pickle

I'm trying to create an instance of an object in Python3 and using pickle to import from a different module.py file having code as:

class absenteeism_model():

```
def __init__(self, model_file, scaler_file):
    # read the 'model' and 'scaler' files which were saved
    with open('model','rb') as model_file, open('scaler', 'rb') as scaler_file:
        
        self.reg = pickle.load(model_file)
        self.scaler = pickle.load(scaler_file)
        self.data = None
```

and my error while creating an instance of the class

```
model = absenteeism_model('model','scaler')
```

is shown as:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-cb3169ea39c9> in <module>
----> 1 model = absenteeism_model('model','scaler')

~\ML_Goals\Absenteeism_from_work_exercise\Integration\absenteeism_module.py in __init__(self, model_file, scaler_file)
     45             with open('model','rb') as model_file, open('scaler', 'rb') as scaler_file:
     46 
---> 47                 self.reg = pickle.load(model_file)
     48                 self.scaler = pickle.load(scaler_file)
     49                 self.data = None

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model.logistic'
```

I've imported the following modules in module.py file :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import  metrics
```

Kindly help and I'll appreciate any suggestions to resolve it.

Comment: sounds like an issue with module versions 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148698/getting-an-error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn-linear-model-l

Comment: Hi, I need a bit more clarity. The above link didn't worked in my case. Should I update my module version in the module.py file manually or there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

Hii Anurag it seems like you have pickled(dump) your model and scaler file in different version and now you are unpickling(loading) it in different version of python .
this is the problem with Pickle, versions should be same for dump and load.
so dump and load with the same version.
i think this might help you..